# Element type "class" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>"

Tags: hibernate

I am getting this xml error everytime at line 6.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC 
           "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"          
           "http://www.hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
    <hibernate-mapping package="com.ida.hibernate">
    <class name="Customer"table="customers"/>
    <id name="cid"column="cid"type="int">
    <genertor class="increment"/>
    </id>
    <property name="cname"column="cname"type="string"/>
    <property name="email"column="email"type="string"/>
    <property name="phone"column="phone"type="long"/>
    <property name="city"column="city"type="string"/>
    <property name="bal"column="bal"type="double"/>
    </class>
    </hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve]

Comment: Missing white spaces al over after the double quotes, typo in genertor, class element closed prematurely by using /> instead of >. And maybe the most important: why are you still using XML, instead of annotations, to map your entities. We're not in 2005 anymore.

Comment: Thank you, it worked for me. I am beginner in hibernate so I was l̥̄earning with XML first and then with annotations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<class name="Customer"table="customers"/>` 

 *==> this is equivalent to `<class name="Customer"table="customers"></class>`*

replace by 

`<class name="Customer" table="customers">`

And Add space between attribute

You can use site like https://codebeautify.org/xmlvalidator or http://xmlbeautifier.com/ to validate and beautify XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<hibernate-mapping package="com.ida.hibernate">
    <class name="Customer" table="customers">
        <id name="cid" column="cid" type="int">
            <genertor class="increment" />
        </id>
        <property name="cname" column="cname" type="string" />
        <property name="email" column="email" type="string" />
        <property name="phone" column="phone" type="long" />
        <property name="city" column="city" type="string" />
        <property name="bal" column="bal" type="double" />
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```